# Random rotation at a given angle?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometric-transform

I need to generate a random rotation matrix for a given angle $a$. In other words, a random $n\times n$ matrix $A$ such that for any unit-length vector $v$ the following is true.

$$v'Av\le\cos a$$

The recipe below visualizes 10000 random rotations with "small" angles, can anyone see how to make it work with specific angle $a$? For $a=\pi/2$ and $n=3$, these rotations correspond to points along the equator in the visualization below

```
(* generate random rotation matrix corresponding to a "small" rotation *)

randomRotation2[n_] := 
  Module[{}, 
   z = IdentityMatrix[n] + 
     0.1 RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {n, n}];
   {q, r} = QRDecomposition[z];
   d = Diagonal[r];
   ph = d/Abs[d];
   q*ph];

n = 3;
points = Table[randomRotation2[n].{0, 0, 1}, {10^4}];
Graphics3D[{{Gray, PointSize[Small], Point[points]}, {Red, Thick, 
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]}}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Can't you use `RotationMatrix[a,{u,v}]` with random vectors `u,v`? From the documentation of `RotationMatrix`: _gives the matrix that rotates by $a$ radians in the plane spanned by $u$ and $v$._

Comment: "a random n×n matrix A such that for any unit-length vector v the following is true: ..." That is only true in 2D. $v^\top A v = 1$  if $v$ is a unit vector along the rotation axis (try `{1, 0, 0}.RotationMatrix[alpha, {1, 0, 0}].{1, 0, 0}` for instance).

Comment: you are right, it needed to be <= insteda of ==, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

For the band region.

```
bandReg = 
  RegionIntersection[HalfSpace[{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 0.8}], 
   HalfSpace[{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0.9}], Sphere[]];
RotationMatrix[{RandomPoint[bandReg], {0, 0, 1}}]
Graphics3D[{Point[RandomPoint[bandReg, 2000]], Opacity[0.1], Ball[]}]
```

[image]

**Update**

```
n = 8;
normal = SparseArray[i_ /; i == n -> -1, {n}] // Normal
pt = SparseArray[i_ /; i == n -> 0.8, {n}] // Normal
center = center = ConstantArray[0, n];
a = HalfSpace[normal, pt] // Region;
b = Sphere[center, 1] // Region;
reg = RegionIntersection[a, b]
RotationMatrix[{RandomPoint[reg], normal}]
```

**Original**

Maybe this?

Or do you want to get angle instead of vector or point?

The answer need to be updated later.

```
a = HalfSpace[{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 0.8}] // Region;
b = Sphere[] // Region;
reg = RegionIntersection[a, b]
RotationMatrix[{RandomPoint[reg], {0, 0, 1}}]
Graphics3D[{Point[RandomPoint[reg, 2000]], Opacity[0.1], Ball[]}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, that's a useful trick....any idea how to exclude rotations close to origin? I tried `RegionIntersection[a, b, 
 RegionDifference[FullRegion[3], HalfSpace[{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 0.9}]]]` but `RandomPoint` fails to evaluate for that region

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov  I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming OP requires rotation matrices for $n\ge 3$ and adapting the algorithm given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50342248/6644522 for Mathematica the following function `genM` generates a $n\times n$ rotation matrix given an axis of rotation `v` in form of an $(n-1)$-subspace (a $n\times(n-1)$ matrix) and an angle `theta`.

```
ArcTan2[y_,x_]/;x\[Element]Reals&&y\[Element]Reals:=Which[x>0||y!=0,2ArcTan[y/(Sqrt[x^2+y^2]+x)],x<0&&y==0,\[Pi],x==0&&y==0,Indeterminate]

genM[v_List,theta_]:=Module[{n,u,M,c,r,t,R},
   n=Length[v[[All,1]]];
   u=v;
   M=IdentityMatrix[n];
   For[c=1,c<=n-2,c++,
      For[r=n,r>=c+1,r--,
         t=ArcTan2[u[[r,c]],u[[r-1,c]]]//N;
         R=IdentityMatrix[n];
         R[[r-1;;r,r-1;;r]]={{Cos[t],-Sin[t]},{Sin[t],Cos[t]}}\[Transpose];
         u=R.u;
         M=R.M;
      ];
   ];
   R=IdentityMatrix[n];
   R[[n-1;;n,n-1;;n]]={{Cos[theta],-Sin[theta]},{Sin[theta],Cos[theta]}};
   LeastSquares[M,R.M]
]
```

where I implemented `ÀrcTan2` based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2. Running

```
genM[{{1}, {2}, {3}}, \[Pi]/4] // N // MatrixForm
genM[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}, \[Pi]/4] // N // MatrixForm
```

gives results consistent with https://stackoverflow.com/a/50342248/6644522:

[image: Matrices]

and the three dimensional rotation matrix is equivalent to `RotationMatrix[\[Pi]/4, {1, 2, 3}]` within floating point precision. The math behind this  (I have not looked into it) can supposedly be found in http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.4.8662.

I am not 100% sure that this implementation in Mathematica is correct: I had to add a `Transpose`, adapt some spans and I do not know if the implementation of `ArcTan2` I have chosen is consistent with `atan2` in MATLAB. I ran some test on against `RotationMatrix` with random angles and axes and in $n=3$ the code seems to work but for $n>3$ I only checked against the on example given for the MATLAB code.